# Binding factory interfaces to factory, except for those that have an implementation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, factory-pattern

I have some factory interfaces.

- **ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory**
- **ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory**

Some factories don't need any implementor, so I can bind them as follows.

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind(services => services
    .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("MyProject")
                 && !a.FullName.Contains("Tests")))
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .EndwingWith("Factory")
    .BindToFactory());
```

Which works flawlessly as long I don't need to provide arguments to the constructor, which should be provided through [**Method Injection**](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MethodInjection).

Besides, using this code, I have bound my `ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory` as well, and it is not bound to its implementer.

**ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory**

```
public interface ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory { 
    CustomerManagementPresenter Create();
}
```

**CustomerManagementPresenterFactory**

```
public class CustomerManagementPresenterFactory : ICustomerManagementPresenterFactory {
    public CustomerManagementPresenterFactory(ICustomerManagementView view
                                            , ICustomerDetailPresenterFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory; 
        this.view = view;
    }

    public CustomerManagementPresenter Create() {
        return new CustomerManagementPresenter(view, factory);
    }

    private readonly ICustomerDetailPresenterfactory factory;
    private readonly ICustomerManagementView view;
}
```

So, because the constructor of **CustomerManagementPresenter** takes two arguments, I wish to implement a factory which won't need to be method injected the dependencies of the class it creates, and I keep using [**Constructor Injection**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

So, I would like to benefit from the [**Convention Binding**](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions), and still bind the two differently.

How might I go about this?

Comment: why are you actually implementing `CustomerManagementPresenterFactory`? Is it because of as soon as possible composition build-up? Ninject would be perfectly able to inject the view and the factory into the presenter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly enough you can't retrieve the list of types "selected" by the convention.
That means you'll have to work around it someway.

The syntax offers the `Where(Func<Type, bool> selector)` and the `Excluding(IEnumerable<Type> types)` methods. So you'd need to get the interface of all implemented factories before binding the interface factories with `.ToFactory()`. For example:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

IList<Type> implementedFactoryInterfaces = new List<Type>();
kernel.Bind(services => services
    .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("MyProject")
                    && !a.FullName.Contains("Tests")))
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .EndingWith("Factory")
    .Where(classFactoryType =>
    {
        implementedFactoryInterfaces.Add(classFactoryType.GetInterfaces().Single());
        return true;
    })
    .BindDefaultInterface());


kernel.Bind(services => services
    .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("MyProject")
                    && !a.FullName.Contains("Tests")))
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .EndingWith("Factory")
    .Excluding(implementedFactoryInterfaces)
    .BindToFactory());
```

An alternative would be to implement a binding generator which check whether there's an implementation for the passed interface-`Type` and create the binding accordingly:

```
public class InterfaceAndClassFactoryBindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        if (!type.IsInterface)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("type", type, "is not an interface, but only interfaces are supported");
        }

        Type classImplementingTheFactoryInterface = type.Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass)
            .SingleOrDefault(type.IsAssignableFrom);

        if (classImplementingTheFactoryInterface == null)
        {
            bindingRoot.Bind(type).ToFactory();
        }
        else
        {
            bindingRoot.Bind(type).To(classImplementingTheFactoryInterface);
        }
    }
}


IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind(services => services
    .From(AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.FullName.Contains("MyProject")
                    && !a.FullName.Contains("Tests")))
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .EndingWith("Factory")
    .BindWith<InterfaceAndClassFactoryBindingGenerator>());
```

Comment: I particularly like the `IBindingGenerator` approach. This will not be used with factories because of another answer of yours which states I don't need parameterized `Factory.Create()` method, and that was the objective, to satisfy the dependencies of a parameterized `Factory.Create()` method. Besides, this can be very useful. =)